# How to invoke Foursquare application from my app in Android phone?

Tags: android, foursquare

I love to send latitude and longitude from my Android application to open in Google Map in Android phone.

But I wonder can we do the same thing with Foursquare application? Just like send the latitude and longitude and bring Foursquare app with place around the position we send to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/wiki/FoursquareIntents